# update on acegi roles for user?

Tags: security, grails, roles, spring-security

If a loggedin user gets a new role, what does he has to do to get all permissions based on this role?

- logout and login again does not work
- reassign the roles with an admin-account works

Do i have to delete all roles given to this user, and reassign them?

Role model is hierarchical.

```
ROLE_POWERUSER > ROLE_USER
```